# String concatenation C issues

Tags: string, arduino, concatenation, particles

I am trying to concatenate multiple integer variables into one string, so that I may then send it as a csv to another program. However, I am unable to get a string. Can you double check this code to make sure it is correct?

This is for a Spark/Particle device that has it's own String library. The only type of "string" I can return is a String type, which is why I'm doing this...

```
void updatePresetVar(void) {
    String s = String();
    int integer = getGrind1;
    String integer_string = String(integer);
    s = String(s + integer_string);
    s = String(s + ",");

    integer = getDuration1;
    integer_string = String(integer);
    s = String(s + integer_string);
    s = String(s + ",");

    integer = getWeight1;
    integer_string = String(integer);
    s = String(s + integer_string);
    s = String(s + ",");

    integer = getGrind2;
    integer_string = String(integer);
    s = String(s + integer_string);
    s = String(s + ",");

    integer = getDuration2;
    integer_string = String(integer);
    s = String(s + integer_string);
    s = String(s + ",");

    integer = getWeight2;
    integer_string = String(integer);
    s = String(s + integer_string);
    s = String(s + ",");

    integer = getGrind3;
    integer_string = String(integer);
    s = String(s + integer_string);
    s = String(s + ",");

    integer = getDuration3;
    integer_string = String(integer);
    s = String(s + integer_string);
    s = String(s + ",");

    integer = getWeight3;
    integer_string = String(integer);
    s = String(s + integer_string);

    presets = String(s);
}
```

edit: Sometimes I get the following output:

�[, or @[, or P

Comment: If they have their own string library, perhaps they have their own functions for concatenating as well? In that case you should probably use those.

Comment: @user3121023 - It compiles fine, so I assume no.

Comment: strcat does not allocate memory for you

Comment: @DCo just becaues it compiles doesn't it's correct or will even work. The problem you have comes from the fact that you didn't allocate memory for `string`.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev changing char* string to char string[128] doesn't change the output.

Comment: @Kninnug - How can I make sure it's allocating memory for it then?

Comment: also you have errors like these: int integer = getGrind1; - you are assigning pointer to function to the variable, to call the function you must add the brackets: int integer = getGrind1();

Comment: @AntonMalyshev I have named the variables that way. Variables in the Particle system are accessed via url/varname, so I wanted it to feel like a getter. It is intentional.

Comment: @DCo does the `String` function copy the C-string you give it? Or does it just take over the pointer? In that case you may need to allocate memory with `malloc`. Otherwise changing it to `char string[<enough space>]` should work.

Comment: @Kninnug I am using this documentation: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringConstructor. I assume I am using it correctly. Can you verify? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @DCo as I suggested: why not use the `String` function directly? Something like: `String integer_string = String(integer); presets = String(integer_string + ",");` and so forth.

Comment: also add string[0] = '\0'; after its initialization for strcat to work

Comment: @Kninnug I have updated my code in the question, but I get the output H[.

Comment: Whatever this library does, if this is *really* C, the `+` will probably add pointers, so it will NOT do what you obviously expect it does.

Comment: @FelixPalmen - I am lost for the solution. Can you help me?

Comment: not really, because I have no documentation of your string library. You should have/find it and look up how concatenations are handled, as @Kninnug commented initially. If it is really C, an operator can't be used for such a thing.

Comment: @FelixPalmen - https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringConstructor. According to this documentation it should work...

Comment: @Kninnug have you had a chance to look at the updated code?

Comment: @DCo By the looks of the documentation you just linked, it's not C

Comment: @DCo according to this site, the `+` is ok. Point is, it's not [tag:c]. "The Arduino language is based on C/C++." -- that's what I read there.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I don't wish to argue the point of is it C or C++. I just want to concatenate a string.

Comment: @DCo you tagged C, confusing ppl trying to give an answer for C. See what a comment discussion you caused. I suggest you remove this tag.